# How to pass a record to controller in html.actionlink of webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using below webgrid to show user details. When I click on Edit link in grid, the corresponding record should move to controller action method, "EditOfflineUser". 
I tried to send item value as shown below. But the value is null in controller
Please let me know how to pass the corresponding record to controller.
In the below code, I'm getting userId value in controller.

CSHtml file

```
@if (Model.OfflineUserList.Count != 0)
{
   WebGrid gridoffline = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: 10, canPage: true);
    gridoffline.Bind(Model.OfflineUserList, autoSortAndPage: true, rowCount: 10);
    @gridoffline.GetHtml(
    fillEmptyRows: false,
    tableStyle: "table",
    headerStyle: "header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "wbgUserOffline" },
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: gridoffline.Columns(
    gridoffline.Column(columnName: "UserName", header: "Username", canSort: false),
    gridoffline.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "Firstname", canSort: false),
    gridoffline.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Lastname", canSort: false),
    gridoffline.Column(columnName: "RegistrationOffice", header: "Registration Office", canSort: false),
    gridoffline.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditOfflineUser", "Admin", new { id = item.UserId, offlineUsers = item }, new { id = "btnEditClick", @class = "edit" })</text>),
    gridoffline.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewOfflineUser", "Admin", new { usrname = item.UserName }, new { @class = "view" })</text>)));
```

}

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditOfflineUser(int id, ListOfUsers offlineUsers)
{
   //getting id value
   //offlineUsers is null
}
```

Model:

```
public class ListOfUsers
{
    public ListOfUsers()
    {
        OnlineUserList = new List<ListOfUsers>();
        OfflineUserList = new List<ListOfUsers>(); 
    }

    public List<ListOfUsers> OnlineUserList { get; set; }
    public List<ListOfUsers> OfflineUserList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> UserCountryList { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationOffice { get; set; }
    public string PositionAtOffice { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: What is `item` in `new { id = item.UserId, offlineUsers = item }`

Comment: Did u able to get the id value in controller

Comment: Do you meam `ListOfUsers` - it does not have a `UserId` property?. And you cant pass models that have collection properties in a query string. You have the `UserId` so just get the model from the database again

Comment: I mentioned about the id that you mention in actionlink as new { id = item.UserId . Did u able to get the item userid on the EditOfflineUser ActionMethod

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get id value in controller.

Comment: @lavanyab, If you have the ID (I assume you have just omitted the `UserId` property from your code) then use that to get the `User` again. But I suspect your models are wrong in any case. You should have one model `User` which has property `ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName` etc and separate model that contains the collections